# http get image 402 payment required

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook graph API to fetch my Facebook page's posts and nextjs with vercel. I get an error GET imageurl 402 payment required even though when in localhost it works perfectly:

[image: the problem]

Maybe there is a problem with vercel or my next.config.js?

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "scontent-*.xx.fbcdn.net", // * wildcard on dynamic part of domain url
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
      },
    ],
    domains: [
      "scontent.fcgm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net",
      "external.fcgm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net",
    ],
  },
  experimental: {
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          protocol: "https",
          hostname: "scontent-*.xx.fbcdn.net", // * wildcard on dynamic part of domain url
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  env: {
    ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've exceeded the 1000 image optimization limite available in vercel for the free tier ?

You can disable that feature in case you don't need it.

```
images: {
    unoptimized: false
}
```